# Can not create new API from the Admin UI in Laminas API Tools

Tags: api, zend-framework, laminas

After I successful installation of Laminas API Tools (formerly Zend APIgility) whenever I try to create new API it always responds back with error message: "I cannot create the API module, please check if already exists". When I check the directory structure there is no such API.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error by changing the ownership to apache user www-data and giving the owner-write permission, as follows:

```
$ sudo chmod 0744 config
$ sudo chown www-data:www-data module
$ sudo chmod 0744 module
$ sudo systemctl reload apache2
```